# Java - copy properties to another object

Tags: java, spring, dto, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a few DTOs (from different APIs) that I need to convert. They have similar, but *different* fields.

Example:

```
class Volkswagen {
  String model;
  int year;
  String colour;
}

class BMW {
  String make;
  int manufactureYear;
  String colour;
}
```

What is the best way to convert these DTOs to my standard DTO?

I know there is `BeanUtils`, but there is not a direct way to map the fields. Currently, I am extracting one set of properties as `VolkswagenMap`, changing its keys using another `V2BMap`, and finally populating my standard DTO using a third `BMWMap`. As in,

```
extract()
   {"model": "Beetle", "year": 1990}
-> {"model": "make", "year": "manufacturedYear"}
-> {"make": "Beetle", "manufacturedYear": 1990}
populate()
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it? Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you read about ModelMapper object mapping library? Here is link: https://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Comment: Would it not be sufficient to add an instance method for each of your dtos to map into your standard dto? I.e. `class Volkswagen {...fields... public StandardDto asStandardDto() {return new StandardDto(this.model, this.year, this.colour);}}`

Comment: Use something like `MapStruct` the `BeanUtils` is intended for internal use for Spring not as a user object

Comment: You could have both implement a common interface (or have an adapter for each that implements a common interface) then all your service methods could operate on the common interface rather than the concrete types

Comment: @boze-noob I do, however, I still want to save a copy of Volkswagen and BMW, so would prefer to convert them after they are parsed in. They may not contain immediately useful information, but storage is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to have a common interface for both. Then all of your service methods could act upon the interface instead of the concrete types.

If you can change the sources of `Volkswagen` and `BMW` you could have both implement a common interface.

If you can't change the sources of `Volkswagen` and `BMW` you could create adapters for each that implement a common interface.

Eg

```
public interface Car {
   int getYear();
   String getModel();
   String getColour();
}
```

```java
public class CarAdapters {
   public static Car asCar(Volkswagen vw) {
      return new Car() {
         public int getYear() { return vw.year(); }
         public String getModel() { return vw.getModel(); }
         public String getColour() { return vw.getColour(); }
      };
   }

   public static Car asCar(BMW bmw) {
      return new Car() {
         public int getYear() { return bmw.getManufactureYear(); }
         public String getModel() { return bmw.getMake(); }
         public String getColour() { return bmw.getColour(); }
      };
   }
}
```

```java
public class CarService {
   public Car paint(Car car, String colour) { ... }
   public void driveForward(Car car, long distance) { ... }
}
```